# C++ how would I cast a string to a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

I'm playing with this C wrapper for the OpenCV function imread.

```
 Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags) {
     return new Mat(cv::imread(*filename, flags));
 }
```

It's failing somewhere I think so I'm trying to test to make sure it's written right. I just need to know how to create a `String*`  to fill its first argument.. I've tried creating a string with

```
 char* filename = "~/home/test.jpg"
```

then casting to `String*` i/e

```
 (String*)filename
```

but that's not working..I've tried many other variations to cast to pointer found online but found nothing `cv_imread` would accept. In my code it's necessary to have the `filename` parameter be a  `String*`  and not another type.  But I could use help creating a `String*` to give to `cv_imread`.

Edit: per your edit I tried

```
 const char* filename = "/home/w/d1";


 cv_imread(new string (filename), 1);
```

but got error:

cannot convert ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}’ to ‘cv::String*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘cv::Mat* cv_imread(cv::String*, int)’
 cv_imread(new string (filename), 1);

If you can help me with it I'd appreciate it

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread), `cv::imread` expects a `const string&`, not a `String*`.  If this is the case, then you can pass a `char*`, and it will automagically be transformed into a `const string&`.

Comment: You need to mention what is `String`, or it is a typo and should be `string` because `cv::imread` does not take `String` or `String*`, or even `string*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string::c_str()` to get the underlying pointer of a string:

```
Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags) {
     return new Mat(cv::imread(filename->c_str(), flags));
}
```

Or you can use `string::data()` too. They have the same functionality after C++11.

---

Edit: OP seems to want to pass a `char*` to `cv_read`. Then should do this:

```
cv_read(new String(filename), 1);
```

Comment: filename.c_str() would be how you do it in this situation.

Comment: @texasbruce  thanks for getting to me so soon...I should have been clearer I need to keep cv_imread the same to test it and just could use help creating the 'String* filename' parameter.  like I as in 'char* filename = "~/home/test.jpg"' is to a 'const char* filename' parameter,  what? is to  a 'String* filename' parameter

Comment: @user3411335 `imread` does not even take `string*`. It takes either a `char *` or a `string&`

Comment: @texasbruce the cv_imread function I posted takes the String*...It's from a library of C wrappers of C++ functions in OpenCV..so I really need to keep as is but also I need to give it  a String* for testing. Can you help me do that.

Comment: @texasbruce sorry just noticed your edit...I tried it though and didn't work....I edited my ? with the results....tried many other things in that same context i/e casting to string pointer with new but none working

Comment: @user3411335 if you are using cv::String, then you should use `String` not `string`

Comment: @texasbruce that worked perfect! Thank you...Any idea how I can save the output of `cv_imread(new String(filename), 1);` to a variable...been trying to do that for awhile

Comment: @user3411335 just do `Mat *result = cv_imread(new String(filename), 1);`

Comment: @texasbruce  Thanks! I just tested and what you posted works,  I accepted your answer and voted it up.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me with that.